# How to implement an operator usable before an instance (pre position)

Tags: c++, operators, operator-overloading

I have a class with the `operator*` taking a scalar as argument, that allow me to perform the multiplication of an instance of my class with a scalar. I'd like to be able to multiply a scalar by an instance of my class (inverse order with the same result). How can I do that ?

Here an example :

```
class Vector3d
{
public:
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z) {
        v[0] = x; v[1] = y; v[2] = z;
    }

    template<typename T>
    Vector3d operator*(const T s) const {
        return( Vector3d( v[0] * s, v[1] * s, v[2] * s)); 
    }

//protected: example purpose
    double v[3];
};

main()
{
    double scalar = 2.0;
    Vector3d vector(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    Vector3d v2 = vector*scalar;
    //This is the operation I want to be able to perform !
    //Vector3d v3 = scalar*vector; 
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to implement it like we do with `ostream<<` operator without success ...

```
template<typename T>
Vector3d operator*(T& s, const Vector3d &v)
{
    return( Vector3d( v[0] * s, v[1] * s, v[2] * s));
}
```

Comment: You say "without success". What happened?

Comment: @dfan `error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘2.0e+0 * vector’ ... :)

Comment: Check my answer below, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must declare your operator* as a nonmember function (outside class) with inverse argument order and call the other one from it

```
template<typename T>
Vector3d<T> operator*(T& s, const Vector3d<T> &v)
{
    return Vector3d(v.v[0] * s, v.v[1] * s, v.v[2] * s);
} 
template<typename T>
Vector3d<T> operator*(const Vector3d<T> &v, T& s)
{
    return s * v; //call the other overload
}
```

And don't forget specifying the template parameters:

```
Vector3d<T>
        ^^^
```

One more issue... Why take `T&` istead of `const T&` or just `T`? In current form you're preventing rvalues to be passed. For example, this wouldn't compile:

```
Vector3d<int> v;
v*3; //3 isn't an lvalue, cannot bind to a nonconst reference
```

Comment: Sorry about the `Vector3d<T>` at the end of my first post forgot to removed it ... `Vector3d` class is not templated in this example ...

Comment: @vrince: That's fine. Shall I edit my answer to present a nontemplate version or it is clear how it should be done?

Comment: Definitely clear to me ... thing is I can't manage to make it work even with those two operators.

Comment: @Sharath: Indeed. Thank you, I'll edit. vrince: does SHarath's comment help?

Comment: @Armen: I did try to pass a rvalue ! You warned me that it wont work ... I replace the argument type by `T` instead of `const &T`.

Comment: Also Vector3d is not a template class at all.

Comment: @Armen, I am unclear about the purpose of Vector3d<T> in the overload function as Vector3d is not a template class. I don't have the <T> tag in my answer below. What exactly is the difference?

Comment: @Sharath: I was assuming that Vector3d is a template class. Vrince later said it wasn't. I suggested to edit for a nontemplate class, but vrince said I needn't. That's all

Answer (score 1):

It is best to do operator overloading outside of the class, that gives you maximum flexibility.

// This compiles fine.

```
class Vector3d
{
public:
    Vector3d(double x, double y, double z) {
        v[0] = x; v[1] = y; v[2] = z;
    }

    double v[3];
};

template<typename T>
Vector3d operator*(const T& s, const Vector3d &v) 
{
    return( Vector3d( v.v[0] * s, v.v[1] * s, v.v[2] * s)); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    double scalar = 2.0;
    Vector3d vector(1.0,2.0,3.0);
    Vector3d v3 = scalar * vector; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank a lot, please see last comment in Armen anwser ... again the error was just in front of the screen :)